# Operation with field's

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-formula

I have field1="ab" "cd" "fg" and field2="ab" "cd" how i can get field3="fg" , distance between the "ab" "cd" ... a new line

Answer (score 3):

The difference of two text lists you can get with `@Replace`:

```
field3 := @Trim(@Replace(field1; field2; ""));
```

`@Replace` replaces all entries in field1 which are also in field2 by an empty string "". The resulting list for your example would have the entries `"" "" "fg"`.

`@Trim` deletes all empty strings from the list. The final result is then `"fg"`.

Make sure that form's field3 has the properties `"Allow multiple values"` and "Multi-Value Options" `New Line`.